# Thinking of getting a server/homelab

Tags: server

I have been using a cluster for my work (mainly running parallelized fortran and matlab codes). And thinking of getting a homelab. It will be a big fixed cost for me to get 2 to 4 nodes up and running since I have never done such a thing. So I would like to start small (with something that can run fortran and matlab), test if I can install slurm and run stuff ...

I was thinking of getting something like this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/154469875388

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this server specifications and experience with similar kind of servers here are some points for consideration:

1. Consume 1400W, multiply it by 24*7 and decide if you are ready to pay this additional electricity bill
2. It is rack mounted, do you have one already?
3. A lot of fans inside so will be noisy
4. A lot of harddisks, will be noisy
5. Did I mention noise?
6. You need to organise kind of cooling, these 1400 watts should be "extracted" somehow.
7. Cooling systems sometime can be noisy
8. You will need switch for interboards and IPMI connectivity